# How to make collectable coins in sidescrolling paltformer as3

Tags: class, actionscript-3

In the coin.as I have put:

```
package  {

    import flash.display.MovieClip;
    import flash.events.*;
    import flash.events.Event;

    public class coin extends MovieClip {

        var player:MovieClip;
        var mainTimeLine = MovieClip(root);
        var coinValue:int = 5;

        public function coin() {
            // constructor code
            this.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, upDate);
        }

        function upDate (e:Event) :void {
            player = MovieClip(root).player;

            if (this.hitTestObject(player)) {
                this.removeEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, upDate);
                this.visible = false;
                mainTimeLine.coinCount += coinValue;
            }
        }

    }

}
```

This works fine when I place coins on the screen for the player the collect them (player coding and other coding is in Main.as) but when I put coins in the collision MovieClip, it traces this error:

```
TypeError: Error #1009: Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
    at coin/upDate()
```

Anything I'm missing or any suggestions to different ways about this I'll be glad to know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your **mainTimeLine** variable is null thus the following line produces the error.

```
mainTimeLine.coinCount += coinValue;
```

**Why.**

Because you initialize it at the moment of coin instantiation, and in that very moment the coin is not attached to the display list. The properties **stage** and **root** of any valid **DisplayObject** are available **ONLY** when the object itself is attached to the display list.

**How to fix it.**

Option 1. Initialize it at the proper moment.

```
// player = MovieClip(root).player;
mainTimeLine = MovieClip(root);
player = mainTimeLine.player;
```

Option 2. Create a class that will keep all the object references you need globally, so you can access them from any piece of code with no regard to your game display list structure.

```
package
{
    public class GameData
    {
        static public var player:PlayerClass;
        static public var game:GameClass;
    }
}
```

So when you start the game you initialize **player** and **game** references at the moment you create them, and then from any place you want you refer them as

```
if (this.hitTestObject(GameData.player)) // ...
```